# Constrain to Margin has different values

Tags: xcode, constraints, xcode9

Maybe this there by design, but why is there a different value for "constrain to margin" on the Superview than "constrain to margin" on a UIView within that Superview? It seems like the standard "constrain to margin" value is 16 pts, but its like 10 when on a UIView. Is there a way I can standardize this value so I can have the same "constrain to margin" value everywhere?

I'm using Xcode 9 with the interface builder. I don't mind using code in my ViewController to accomplish this if necessary.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way I can standardize this value so I can have the same
>   "constrain to margin" value everywhere?

No this can´t be done in Xcode atm.

Why there is different standard margins, this is by Apple design and what they have chosen as their graphical profile.